# Get all duplicate named customers based on another tables value

Tags: sql

I have the following 4 tables:

Customers:

```
+----+------------+-----------+
| id | first_name | last_name |....
+----+------------+-----------+
|  1 | bob        | dylan     |
|  2 | alice      | brown     |
|  3 | liv        | green     |
|  4 | bob        | dylan     |
+----+------------+-----------+
```

Orders:

```
+----+-------------+
| id | customer_id |....
+----+-------------+
|  1 |           1 |
|  2 |           2 |
|  3 |           3 |
|  4 |           4 |
+----+-------------+
```

Order Item:

```
+----+-----------+----------+
| id | order_id  | fruit_id |....
+----+-----------+----------+
|  1 |         1 |        1 |
|  2 |         2 |        2 |
|  3 |         3 |        3 |
|  4 |         4 |        4 |
+----+-----------+----------+
```

Fruits:

```
+----+--------------+
| id | taste_rating | .....
+----+--------------+
|  1 |            5 |
|  2 |            5 |
|  3 |            2 |
|  4 |            5 |
+----+--------------+
```

I am trying to get all the users who share the same `first_name` and `last_name` who have ONLY ordered fruit with a `taste_rating` of `5`

#### Example output based on above tables:

```
+-------+-------+------------+-----------+
| u1_id | u2_id | first_name | last_name |
+-------+-------+------------+-----------+
|     1 |     4 | bob        | dylan     |
+-------+-------+------------+-----------+
```

This is because in `customers` there are 2 "Bob Dylan" when joining them with `orders` we get the 2 ids of `1` & `4` then joining that with `order_item`, we get `fruit_id` of `1` & `4`. Lastly when getting the fruits from the `fruit_id`, we see that the `id` of both `1` & `4` have the `taste_rating` of 5.

I have tried the following query:

```sql
SELECT customers.id, customers.first_name, customers.last_name
FROM customers 
INNER JOIN orders ON orders.customer_id = customers.id
INNER JOIN order_item ON order_item.order_id = orders.id
INNER JOIN fruits ON fruits.id = order_item.fruits_id
WHERE fruits.id IN (
        SELECT fruits.id
        FROM fruits
        GROUP BY fruits.id
        HAVING taste_rating = 5)
GROUP BY customers.first_name, customers.last_name, customers.id, fruits.taste_rating
```

This gets me all the users who have only had orders with a `taste_rating = 5` although I am unsure then how to get only those who have the same `first_name` & `last_name`

Answer (score 1):

When you don't group by customers.id.
Then the count of unique customers id's won't be 1 for the customers that have more than 1 id.
*(or different people that share the same name)*

That they only ordered the 5 ratings, some conditional aggregation checks could help with that.

> ```
> SELECT 
>   MIN(cust.id) AS u1_id
> , MAX(cust.id) AS u2_id
> , cust.first_name
> , cust.last_name
> --, COUNT(DISTINCT cust.id) AS TotalUniqCustId
> --, COUNT(DISTINCT fruit.id) AS TotalFruitId
> --, MAX(CASE WHEN fruit.taste_rating != 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS HadBeside5
> --, COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN fruit.taste_rating = 5 THEN cust.id END) AS TotalCustHad5
> FROM customers AS cust
> INNER JOIN orders ON orders.customer_id = cust.id
> INNER JOIN order_item AS itm ON itm.order_id = orders.id
> LEFT JOIN fruits AS fruit ON fruit.id = itm.fruit_id
> GROUP BY cust.first_name, cust.last_name
> HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT cust.id) >= 2 -- same name users
>    AND MAX(CASE WHEN fruit.taste_rating != 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0
>    AND COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN fruit.taste_rating = 5 THEN cust.id END) >= 2
> ;
> ```

| u1_id | u2_id | first_name | last_name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 | bob | dylan |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=2c200267265520e4766424c73a73eff8)*

Comment: This gives me all users who have at least one rating of `5` rather than EVERY rating of `5`. This also doesn't give me the user id's of the two users who share the same name.

Comment: @bobdylan01 Check update. Now with fiddle.

Comment: This still doesn't give me the `id` of the customers who share the same name. The example output table in my question is how the output should look. I don't care about totals

Comment: Ok, now with id's and no totals.